# after u see a valid number, no letter can come after it. how can i solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

“All vanity plates must start with at least two letters.”

“… vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters.”

“Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate; ***AAA22A would not be acceptable.*** The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”

“No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.”

I solved ever problem but i am having a difficult time solving the highlighted problem. AAA22A or AAA2A as invalid.

```
def is_valid(s):
    # checks for at least 2 chars and a max of 6 characters
    # and checks for at least 2 uppercase letters
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6 and s[0:2].isalpha():
        return False

    # checks for periods, spaces, or punctuation marks
    for i in s:
        if i in [".", " ", "!", "?"]:
            return False

    # checks if numbers in string starts with 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i].isalpha() == False:
            if s[i] == "0":
                return False
            else:
                break
        i += 1

    # after u see a valid number, no letter can come after it 
    # this is where the challenge is ,
    for i in s[::-1]:
        if s[i].isalpha() == True:
            for j in s[::-2]:
                if s[j].isalpha == False:
                    return False
                else:
                    break
        else:
            break
    # returns true if all the requirements are passed
    return True
```

"""i tried to iterate in reverse order but that deems unsuccessful. Not sure how to solve. need help please."""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a function to know if a letter comes after a number or use this piece of code directly:

```
def letter_after_number(s):
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i].isdigit() and s[i + 1].isalpha():
            return False
    return True
```

here the entire code:

```
def is_valid(s):
    # checks for at least 2 chars and a max of 6 characters
    # and checks for at least 2 uppercase letters
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6 and s[0:2].isalpha():
        return False

    # checks for periods, spaces, or punctuation marks
    for i in s:
        if i in [".", " ", "!", "?"]:
            return False

    # checks if numbers in string starts with 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i].isalpha() == False:
            if s[i] == "0":
                return False
            else:
                break
        i += 1

    # after u see a valid number, no letter can come after it 
    # this is where the challenge is ,
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i].isdigit() and s[i + 1].isalpha():
            return False

    # returns true if all the requirements are passed
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help Roniel López, can you please explain that line of code. It worked and is very simple but I am unsure if you're iterating from left to right or iterating in reverse. I dont understand fully all the possible ways to use the range function. thanks

Comment: Sure, the for loop iterates through the elements of `s` from index 0 to the second-last index (`len(s) - 1`), and the if statement checks if the current element (`s[i]`) is a digit and the next element (`s[i + 1]`) is a letter, If the condition is true, the function returns False

Answer (score 0):

So, you don't have to go in reverse order to check if there's a letter. I would iterate over the letters until you get to a character that's a number. Once you do that, you can check that the rest of the characters are numbers.

If you did want to go in reverse, you can apply the same logic: iterate backwards, checking that you're only reading numbers. Once you hit a letter, check that the rest of the string is only letters. You can do this in multiple ways, such as using set operations or just checking the character is the correct type.

Also, note that you don't have to/shouldn't use True/False in the conditional statements. It's better to use something like `if s[i].isalpha()` and `if not s[i].isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good use of regular expressions. This pattern only matches strings that have an optional group of letters followed by an optional group of numbers. The pattern also omits special characters by design.

```
import re

def is_valid(s):
    
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return False
    
    # regular expression with two capture groups
    pattern = "^([a-zA-Z]{0,6})([0-9]{0,6})$"
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    
    if m is None:
        return False
    
    alpha = m.group(1)
    numeric = m.group(2)
    
    # first digit is not zero
    if numeric[0]=="0":
        return False
    
    return True
```